# Wrong Screen width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

What is the diference betwen use the next code,  to get screen width and height in android :

```
 public HorseView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
.............
}
```

And  use the another this:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
    int height = this.getHeight();
}
```

Anyone know why in firs case, height is set to 508; and in the second case is 533;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator or device have diferent density:

- ldpi=.75,
- mdpi=1,
- hdpi=1.5,
- xhdpi=2

The status bar icons have a height of 25dp (mdpi). For all densities the bar height: 25*(ldpi=.75, mdpi=1, hdpi=1.5, xhdpi=2) = (19px, 25px, 38px, 50px).

We can use 25dp as the base and multiply it by the density (rounded up) to get the status bar height on any device:

```
int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Finally, the dimension that the application can use, if you have context, is:

```
int heightAreaWork = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - statusBarHeight;
```

Answer (score 3):

- 533 * 1.5 = 800.
- 508 * 1.5 = 762.

The difference between the two value is because of the the height of notification bar, which is 38px height.

Comment: Just to elaborate. One is measuring the screen size. While the other is measuring the surface size of something. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     int height=display.getHeight();
              int width=display.getWidth();
```

Comment: I'm calling this outside of an Activity. getWindowManager() not work there.